# Why doesn't the bib file work when I change the name of the tex file?

Tags: bibtex, compiling, naming

Suppose I create a tex and a bib file. They work fine. Then I rename the tex file, and keep the same (old) name for the bib file. When I compile the new tex file, the bibliography does not work - just comes up with "?" signs.

Why does this happen, and how do I rectify this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using \jobname for the designation of the .bib file? A minimum working example (MWE) would be handy.

Comment: Have you run bibtex for the new name?

Comment: I am not sure what \jobname means @HerbSchulz

Comment: tex never reads the bib file, you need to re-run bibtex to generate a bibliography for the new document

Comment: Suppose your tex file is called `main.tex`. When BibTeX is run, it creates a file called `main.bbl`, which contains the formatted bibliographic items. The file `main.bbl` is read by LaTeX during the next compilation run, and the result is the bibliography section in your pdf file. Now, if you rename the main tex file to, say, `wow.tex`, LaTeX will look for a file called `wow.bbl` for the formatted bibliographic items ... and comes up empty. Two possible remedies: (i) re-run BibTeX (to create `wow.bbl` from scratch); or (ii) rename the file `main.bbl` to `wow.bbl`. Then, rerun LaTeX twice more.